# Changing x and y labels on a bar plot

Tags: r, bar-chart

I'm looking to figure out how to change the x-labels that show the default M and F variables from the data frame to become "Male" and "Female" instead. I tried looking online, but I still couldn't seem to find the best approach for this.

This is my code

```
# Create a visualization between males and female subjects
ggplot(data=subjectID,aes(x=Sex,fill=Sex))+geom_bar(col="black") + 
  xlab("Sex") + ylab("Count") + ggtitle("Count Between Males and Females")
```

This gets me to generate a graph that looks like this below. Any help on changing this would be appreciated thank you!

[image]

Comment: [https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_discrete.html](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_discrete.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is not with the graph label names. The M and F are the two unique values in your column Sex of `subjectID` data frame, which are being plotted. Instead of changing the x and y labels, you need to replace the M and F to Male and Female respectively in your Sex column of `subjectID` dataframe.

This code might help you fix the issue.
`subjectID[subjectID=="M"]<-'Male'`
`subjectID[subjectID=="F"]<-'Female'`

Run these two lines before plotting the graph